# abp getRemoteServiceBaseUrl not getting the value

Tags: angular, aspnetboilerplate, boilerplate

Currently i am adding abp to my angular project. I have added abp-ng2-module and abp-web-resources npm packages and in angular.json i have added the abp scripts and assets. Also i have moved the shared folder and appPreBootstrap to my new project. But i am facing the issue with setting the api url. In app.module.ts i have the below code

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        SharedModule.forRoot(),
        ServiceProxyModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot(),
        PartialsModule,
        CoreModule,
        OverlayModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {metaReducers}),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
        StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot({stateKey: 'router'}),
        StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument(),
        AuthModule.forRoot(),
        TranslateModule.forRoot(),
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        InlineSVGModule.forRoot(),
        ThemeModule,
        ToastrModule.forRoot(), // ToastrModule added,

    ],
    exports: [],
    providers: [

        MessageService,
        LogService,
        AbpHttpConfiguration,
        AbpMultiTenancyService,
        LocalizationService,
        AppSessionService,
        PermissionCheckerService,
        FeatureCheckerService,
        NotifyService,
        SettingService,
        LayoutConfigService,
        LayoutRefService,
        MenuConfigService,
        PageConfigService,
        KtDialogService,
        DataTableService,
        SplashScreenService,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: appInitializerFactory,
            deps: [Injector, PlatformLocation],
            multi: true
        },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AbpHttpInterceptor, multi: true },
        { provide: API_BASE_URL, useFactory: getRemoteServiceBaseUrl },


        {
            provide: LOCALE_ID,
            useFactory: getCurrentLanguage
        },
        {
            provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG,
            useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG
        },
        {
            provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,
            useClass: GestureConfig
        }
        ,
        {
            // layout config initializer
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initializeLayoutConfig,
            deps: [LayoutConfigService], multi: true
        },
        {
            provide: HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS,
            useValue: {languages: hljsLanguages}
        },

        // template services
        SubheaderService,
        MenuHorizontalService,
        MenuAsideService,
        HttpUtilsService,
        TypesUtilsService,
        LayoutUtilsService,
        PredictionServiceProxy,
        KnowledgeBaseServiceProxy

    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

When i load the app the getRemoteServiceBaseUrl calling before setting the app configurations. Because of this i am unable to make the server calls. Am i missing anything? I am using abp-ng2-module and abp-web-resources version 5.2.0.

Comment: How is `getRemoteServiceBaseUrl` implemented?

Comment: Its a mistake. I have imported my module in two places. Now everything works fine. thanks